# Where can I find a variable about max bin log files in Maria DB ( I aint mean to say max_binlog_size)

Tags: amazon-web-services, mariadb, rds, binlog

Too many binary log files are in the disk.

the number of log files keep 14~16 as below. (normally 14)

mysql-bin-changelog.028255  134223043

mysql-bin-changelog.028256  134228506

mysql-bin-changelog.028257  134220246

mysql-bin-changelog.028258  134236483

mysql-bin-changelog.028259  134219139

mysql-bin-changelog.028260  134224849

mysql-bin-changelog.028261  134219266

mysql-bin-changelog.028262  134227092

mysql-bin-changelog.028263  16064294

mysql-bin-changelog.028264  134218994

mysql-bin-changelog.028265  134221078

mysql-bin-changelog.028266  134222337

mysql-bin-changelog.028267  134231770

mysql-bin-changelog.028268  134222330

mysql-bin-changelog.028269  119753944

I am pretty sure that the last tabs like '134227341' are from a global variable called max_binlog_size. but what makes the list keeps its size?

I did not set up this Maria DB, so I do not much about it. this is for RDS and MariaDB ver 10.x and no replication out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you set `expire_logs_days` to, say, 14.  This would mean that any binlogs older than 14 days would be automatically deleted.

14 days should give you enough time to notice that a Slave is broken and fix it before losing the binlogs that it needs.

If you have not slaves *and* you don't use binlogs for backup, then set it to 1.

(There are other approaches, but this is reasonably simple.)